# Checking a Query's validity before submitting when using the Rally Rest API

Tags: java, rally

I have a UI interface where my users can set up the parameters for a query in Rally.  When they define a query, I want to check that it will be valid before I send the query() request.  This will help a lot with the members of items that only have certain allowed values, like how the ScheduleState of a HierarchicalRequirement only has 4 possible values.   I think it would be more practical, and less time consuming, to not have all that information hardcoded and retrieve it from Rally if possible.  Does anyone know if there is a way to dynamically retrieve the allowable values of any field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find that information by querying the [TypeDefinition's](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/body.jsp#TypeDefinition) and looking at the collection of [AttributeDefinitions](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/body.jsp#AttributeDefinition). On each Attribute Definition there is a collection called AllowedValues, that is where you will find what the legal options are for that field.